# any one knows how to make equal div height in same row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make each div in same row with equal height but unable to do can any one help me to do this?

what my code does it makes whole div with same height but i don't want like that i want like table structure where if in a row any div exceeds with max height then only only for that row all the div should be with same height other wise it should not

Thanks in advance

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Template</title>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8000/css/style.css"/>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.col-data-ss
{
    border:1px solid;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="table-heading">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-lg-3 empty-head data-h">

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 data-expe data-h">
                Experian
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 data-equi data-h">
                Equifax
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 data-trans data-h">
                TransUnion
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table-data-st">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="first-col col-data-ss"> Account Name: </div>
      <div class="first-col col-data-ss"> Account Number: </div>
      <div class="first-col col-data-ss"> Account Type: </div>
      <div class="first-col col-data-ss"> Account Status: </div>
      <div class="first-col col-data-ss"> Monthly Payment: </div>
      <div class="first-col col-data-ss"> Date Opened: </div>
      <div class="first-col col-data-ss"> Balance: </div>
      <div class="first-col col-data-ss"> Terms: </div>
      <div class="first-col col-data-ss"> High Balance: </div>
      <div class="first-col col-data-ss"> Limit: </div>
      <div class="first-col col-data-ss"> Past Due: </div>
      <div class="first-col col-data-ss"> Payment Status: </div>
      <div class="first-col col-data-ss"> Comments: </div>
    </div>
    <div  class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="col-data-ss">H &amp; R ACCOUNTS INC kdjsfh k dfkjhd kfjdskfjhdskj fhkjdsh fkjdhf kjhdkjsf h</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">1000528879d8897897987897897987987897</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">Collection Department / Agency / Attorney dsfkj hdskjf kdjsjfh kjjdshkjf hkjdsh fjkhdskjfh jkdshkf hkdshf kjhdsjfh jkdshjf hjkdshf jkhdsjkf hjkdsh jkfhjdks hkfjhdsk hfkjdsh kjfhdkjsh fkjhdskjf hkjdsh fjkdhskjf hkjdsh fkjhdskfh kjdshkjf hkjsdhf kjsdhkjf hkdsjhf kjhdskjhf kjshd f</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">Closed</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">3/1/2012</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">$4519.00</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">1 Month</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">$4519.00</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">Seriously past due date / assigned to attorney, collection agency, or credit grantor's internal collection department</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div  class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="col-data-ss">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">1000528</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">Collection Account</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">Closed</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">8/1/2013</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">$4519.00</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">$4519.00</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">Unpaid</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">MEDICAL
        Unpaid</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="col-data-ss">MED1 02 ST FRANCIS HOSPITAL</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">1000528</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">Collection Account</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">Open</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">8/1/2013</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">$3519.00</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-data-ss">Placed for collection</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     var i=0; 
     $('.row').each(function(){ 
               var highestBox = 0;
               $('.col-data-ss', this).each(function(){
               if($(this).height() > highestBox) 
                      highestBox = $(this).height(); 
               });  
         $('.col-data-ss',this).height(highestBox);

   });  
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add your css style sheets

Comment: now run my code i have added style

Comment: Flexboxes. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: If you want a table structure, why not use a table?

Comment: Or `display: table`.

Comment: So, you want if in one of all columns you have 4 lines, every column should have height like 4 lines column?

Comment: i think div is preferable option i can not change my design now i have to use div only,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do what you are wanting in the end by changing the structure of your HTML, such as:

```
<div class="table-data-st">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="first-col col-data-ss">Account Name:</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">row 1 col 2 data</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">row 1 col 3 data</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">row 1 col 4 data</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="first-col col-data-ss">Account Type:</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">row 2 col 2 data</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">row 2 col 3 data</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">row 2 col 4 data</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want that structure only its clients need

Comment: $( "#table-data-st .row > .col-lg-3:nth-child(4)" ).height('20px') would set all of the 4th row in your original example to 20px high, that might be the thing that you are missing in your javascript.

Comment: ya i know you can delete my jquery code then run it you will get the idea what i want